# Correct Way to Define a Predicate Function in C++

Tags: c++, stl, predicate

I'm trying to write predicate function for use with STL algorithms. I see that they are two ways to define a predicate:

(1) Use a simple function as below:

```
bool isEven(unsigned int i) { return (i % 2 == 0); }

std::find_if(itBegin, itEnd, isEven);
```

(2) Use the operator() function as below:

```
class checker {  
public:  
    bool operator()(unsigned int i) { return (i % 2 == 0); }  
}; 
    
std::find_if(itBegin, itEnd, checker);
```

I have more use for the second type as I usually would like to create a predicate object with some members in it and use them in the algorithm. When I add the same isEven function inside checker and use it as a predicate, I get an error:
3. Syntax which gives error:

```
class checker { 
    public: 
       bool isEven(unsigned int i) 
       { return (i%2 == 0); }
}; 

checker c; 
std::find_if(itBegin, itEnd, c.isEven);
```

Calling c.isEven gives an error during compilation saying undefined reference to some function. Can someone explain why 3. is giving error? Also, I would appreciate any pointers to read about predicate and iterator basics.

Comment: See if your compiler is modern enough to support using a lambda, something like: `std::find_if(itBegin, itEnd, [](int i){ return i%2 == 0;});`.

Comment: @jerry - thanks..looks like a cool idea. But I guess we are sacrificing code re-use for exotic syntax :).  If I have a functor, I can re-use it later and it is easier to maintain

Comment: Yes -- if you have a functor that really stands a good chance of being used in a lot of places, then a lambda may not be the best route. At the same time, for trivial code like this, the gain from having it all directly visible can outweigh the (possible) loss from repetition. At the same time, I have to add that it's probably best *not* to think of the syntax as "exotic" -- the new standard that includes it is being finalized, and most current compilers already support it; expect to see it in wide use soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess it's because the type of `c.isEven()` is,

```
bool (checker::*)(unsigned int) // member function of class
```

which may not be expected by `find_if()`. `std::find_if` should be expecting either a function pointer (`bool (*)(unsigned int)`) or a function object.

**Edit**: Another constraint: A non-`static` **member function pointer must be called by the `class` object**. In your case, even if you succeed to pass the member function then still `find_if()` will not have any information about any `checker` object; so it doesn't make sense to have `find_if()` overloaded for accepting a member function pointer argument.

**Note**: In general `c.isEven` is not the right way to pass member function pointer; it should be passed as, `&checker::isEven`.

Comment: I understand that the STL algos. are looking for function pointers. But why does Syntax 1. calling a regular function such as isEven work. Why is that treated as function pointer by g++..

Comment: @srikrish, because in syntax 1 you have stand alone function; which doesn't depend on any `class` object. If you see definition of `find_if` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/), you can see the `predicate` is a `template` parameter. It could be resolved to a function pointer (not class member function pointer).

Answer (score 15):

A pointer to a member function requires an instance to be called on, and you are passing only the member function pointer to `std::find_if` (actually your syntax is incorrect, so it doesn't work at all; the correct syntax is `std::find_if(itBegin, itEnd, &checker::isEven)` which then still doesn't work for the reasons I gave).

The `find_if` function expects to be able to call the function using a single parameter (the object to test), but it actually needs two to call a member function: the instance `this` pointer and the object to compare.

Overloading `operator()` allows you to pass both the instance and the function object at the same time, because they're now the same thing. With a member function pointer you must pass two pieces of information to a function that expects only one.

There is a way to do this using `std::bind` (which requires the `<functional>` header):

```
checker c;
std::find_if(itBegin, itEnd, std::bind(&checker::isEven, &c, std::placeholders::_1));
```

If your compiler doesn't support `std::bind`, you can also use `boost::bind` for this. Though there's no real advantage to doing this over just overloading `operator()`.

---

To elaborate a bit more, `std::find_if` expects a function pointer matching the signature `bool (*pred)(unsigned int)` or something that behaves that way. It doesn't actually need to be a function pointer, because the type of the predicate is bound by the template. Anything that behaves like a `bool (*pred)(unsigned int)` is acceptable, which is why functors work: they can be called with a single parameter and return a `bool`.

As others have pointed out, the type of `checker::isEven` is `bool (checker::*pred)(unsigned int)` which doesn't behave like the original function pointer, because it needs an instance of `checker` to be called on.

A pointer to a member function can be conceptually considered as a regular function pointer that takes an additional argument, the `this` pointer (e.g. `bool (*pred)(checker*, unsigned int)`). You can actually generate a wrapper that can be called that way using `std::mem_fn(&checker::isEven)` (also from `<functional>`). That still doesn't help you, because now you have a function object that must be called with two parameters rather than only one, which `std::find_if` still doesn't like.

Using `std::bind` treats the pointer to a member function as if it was a function taking the `this` pointer as its first argument. The arguments passed to `std::bind` specify that the first argument should always be `&c`, and the second argument should bind to the first argument of the newly returned function object. This function object is a wrapper that can be called with one argument, and can therefore be used with `std::find_if`.

Although the return type of `std::bind` is unspecified, you can convert it to a `std::function<bool(unsigned int)>` (in this particular case) if you need to refer to the bound function object explicitly rather than passing it straight to another function like I did in my example.

Answer (score 4):

`checker::isEven` is not a function; it is a member function. And you cannot call a non-static member function without a reference to a `checker` object. So you can't just use a member function in any old place that you could pass a function pointer. Member pointers have special syntax that requires more than just `()` to call.

That's why functors use `operator()`; this makes the object callable without having to use a member function pointer.

Comment: I have called isEven which is a non-static member function with c (which is an object of checker) - I do not understand "you cannot call a non-static member function without a reference to a checker object".

Comment: @srikrish: There is a difference between calling a function and passing that function to someone else who will call it. You can call a member function through an object just fine. But you can't pass a member function to some other code that will call it, unless that code knows its receiving a member function. std::find_if needs to be passed something it can use `()` to call, and a member function isn't sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer [functors](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch13_Functors.pdf) (function objects) because make your program more readable and, more importantly, expressing the intent clearly.

This is my favorite example:

```
template <typename N>
struct multiplies
{
  N operator() (const N& x, const N& y) { return x * y; }
};

vector<int> nums{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

// Example accumulate with transparent operator functor 
double result = accumulate(cbegin(nums), cend(nums), 1.1, multiplies<>());
```

Note: In recent years we've got a [lambda expression](http://www.umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/Lambda.pdf) support.

```
// Same example with lambda expression
double result = accumulate(cbegin(nums), cend(nums), 1.1,
                            [](double x, double y) { return x * y; });
```

Comment: Why have you used 1.1 and not 1 in the call to accumulate()?

Comment: Also, why not std::multiplies? That works better - `multiplies<>`  in this example doesn't work because `N` has no default. `std::multiplies<>` has overloaded operators.

Answer (score 1):

The example given says you should use the call operator (`operator()`) whereas in your example you've called your function `isEven`. Try re-writing it as:

```
class checker { 
    public: 
       bool operator()(unsigned int i) 
       { return (i%2 == 0); }
};
```